# Drawing concentric circle in c# windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to draw a circle on groupbox, size of circle should instantaneously change when the textbox input is changed.

```
private void groupBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //CIRCLE
    Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
    float S = float.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(50, 50, (int)S, (int)S);
    graphics.DrawEllipse(p, r);
    graphics.Dispose();
}
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    groupBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.groupBox1_Paint); 
    this.Controls.Add(groupBox1);
}
```

Comment: Do not Dispose your graphics (unless you created the graphics in your code yourself). Also, add event handler for `Paint` once in the constructor of your form, because this way it will add multiple handlers as duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call the Paint method directly. Instead, you usually let Windows decide when to redraw by calling `groupBox1.Invalidate();`.

The reason is, that the control might be hidden or that too many paint requests are pending. Then Windows might to decide to drop some of them.

**Don't** re-add your control with `this.Controls.Add(groupBox1);`!

**Don't** re-subscribe the event handler. Either subscribe it once in the constructor (with `+=`) or do it from the forms designer by switching the properties window to the events (click on the flash symbol) and then double clicking the paint event.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    groupBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

If the refresh must be really very immediate (but that's probably only the case if you are doing an animation), then call `groupBox1.Refresh();`;

See: [Whats the difference between Control.Invalidate, Control.Update and Control.Refresh?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/subhagpo/2005/02/22/whats-the-difference-between-control-invalidate-control-update-and-control-refresh/)

---

Events work like this: methods wanting to do something when the event is risen, subscribe to the event (only once!) with `+=`. You can do this either manually in code or (easier) in the forms designer. Then some logic raises the event. In this case the logic is hidden in the `Invalidate` method. Then all the methods that subscribed the event are executed.

See: [How to: Raise and Consume Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16(v=vs.110).aspx).
By googling C# events you will find a lot of tutorials and examples.

Comment: He confused adding event handler of painting and invoking the paint (invalidation). However, he should add code for `Paint` event once, (maybe at constructor), not every time.

Comment: Does `GroupBox` have a `Paint` event?  I don't see one in the docs.

Comment: Every control and the forms themselves are derived (either directly or indirectly) from [System.Windows.Forms.Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and this one defines the `Paint` event (and most of the other members of the controls).

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I am trying to learn so please accept my apology if it was silly. One of the problem was that:  float.Parse(textBox1.Text) doesn't seem to be able to get the entry from textbox. Any suggestions on that ?

Comment: Also what would be the easiest way to connect the textbox entry change to my circle instantly? I thought 
    groupBox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.groupBox1_Paint);                       would do that for me

Comment: Look at [Winforms Data Binding](http://www.google.ch/search?q=winforms%20data%20binding) instead of struggling with parsing and conversions.

Comment: The easiest way of attaching the `Paint` event is in the forms designer (see my answer). Calling it with `groupBox1.Invalidate()`.

Comment: The problem now is groupBox1.Invalidate() or groupBox1.Refresh() is making the drawing flicker.

Comment: [How to: Reduce Graphics Flicker with Double Buffering for Forms and Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t7htc9c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)